# DropDownCheckBoxes and calendar are not working on same aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm facing an issue that when I use `DropDownCheckBoxesLab` and a textbox to display calendar `((".startDate").datepicker)` then calendar does not popup/opens to select date. However if I remove `DropDownCheckBoxesLab` from code, then the calendar works.
Is there any compatibility issue using both or am I missing something here?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".startDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            buttonImage: "/images/calendar.gif",
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" >
                <cc1:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="DropDownCheckBoxesLab" runat="server" 
                    ToolTip="Select Program" AddJQueryReference="True" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" UseButtons="False" UseSelectAllNode="True" AutoPostBack="true"  onselectedindexchanged="DropDownCheckBoxesLab_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Select Program" />
                 </cc1:DropDownCheckBoxes>
             </td>
             <td align="left">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="startDate"> </asp:TextBox>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>            
 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Could you please check again by placing the script section at the end of asp:Content instead of at the beginning. Also see if you are getting any js error in console due to the control you are adding because this may also be blocking datepicker script from running.

Comment: I tried by placing the script section at the end of asp:Content, but results are same. I see below error in console: 
 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (ReportCostAndEffort.aspx:143)
    at Object.resolveWith (WebResource.axd?d=iznuS5Sosk1...00:16)
    at Function.ready (WebResource.axd?d=iznuS5Sosk1...00:16)
    at HTMLDocument.z (WebResource.axd?d=iznuS5Sosk1...00:16)

Comment: When i added <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> then calendar starts working, but DropDownCheckBoxes stops working. On click of it, nothing happens. i get error
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hitch is not a function
    at DropDownScript.initEvents

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Problem occurs when using Masterpages. Try setting `AddJQueryReference="False"` in `DropDownCheckBoxes`.